# LED-strip PWM works with Raspberry Pi, doesn't work with Attiny45

Tags: pwm, avr, led-strip, attiny

I'm trying to control an RGBW analog LED-strip by PWM modulation.

When using an Attiny45 the LED-strip just blinks at a low frequency (approx. 2-3 hz). However, using a Raspberry Pi 3 to control PWM works without a problem, and at any frequency of PWM I try.

Any ideas as to why that could be?

*Additional information*

In my test setup I power the Attiny45 by connecting to the 3.3V pin on the Pi (for now, will change later).

I have programmed the Attiny45 via SPI on the Pi using the Avrdude linuxspi module, following [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Programming-the-ATtiny85-from-Raspberry-Pi/) instructable.

The setup is the same for both tested controllers:

The control pin with PWM output drives a MOSFET (IRLZ34NPBF), which connects one of the color leads on the strip to ground (which is connected to the Pi's ground).

An external power supply, rated for use with my LED-strip powers the strip, with the ground connected to the Pi's ground.

I have tried all different PWM frequencies on the Attiny45 (by default clocked at 8MHz, so I shouldn't even see a flicker on the lowest PWM frequency, which is 8MHz/(256*1024)=~30.5Hz (according to the official [Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf), page 74)) and the same frequency on the Pi, which works without flickering.

The Attiny45 can drive a single LED using the same MOSFET setup without flickering.

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkuidY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried adding a small value resistor (R1, 620Ohm) between gate and source of the MOSFET to counteract a floating state when the PWM is off, but it doesn't make a difference.

I'm looking forward to your input!

Comment: Are you confident the clock rates are programmed the same?

Comment: Is there any difference in Vgs?  >=4V is preferred over 3.3V

Comment: "I have tried all different PWM frequencies on the Attiny45" - exactly how did you do this?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The Attiny45 has its fuses set to use the internal oscillator at 8mhz, using the formula given in the datasheet i calculated the pwm frequency. On the Raspberry Pi the PWM frequency can be set using the GPIO.PWM() setup function. Sadly, I can't measure the actual output because I don't own an oscilloscope...

Comment: Also @SunnyskyguyEE75, the Raspberry Pi uses 3.3V on its GPIO pins, and since I power the Attiny45 off the 3.3V pin of the Pi it too uses 3.3V. I tried to power it off the 5V pin of the Pi, but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @BruceAbbott using a simple program that just activates PWM on the Attiny45 and reprogramming and testing the Attiny while going through all the different clock settings.

Comment: You can measure f with a CD4060 or similar ripple counter, divide by 1e12+ or roughly 4 million and use an LED to count low f rate around 1 Hz

Answer (score 4):

Well, after some random tinkering I found that when I ground the attiny45 in a specific place on my breadboard setup it works without a problem. Therefore I think the problems I had had nothing to do with the chip itself, just some weird problem with my breadboard/jumpercables/etc..

Sorry for not trying that earlier and thank you all for your help!